# Angular 6/7 css media queries are not applied on grand-child

Tags: html, css, media-queries, angular6, angular7

I'm having some issues on apply media queries (for responsive behavior) on an app that it's using the following component's architecture

- **base components:** It uses default encapsulation, there is where external plugins are used, at the moment we're applying, for some cases, PrimeNG external module. The idea is to move these base components to other apps. These are integrated in its own shared module.
- **branding components:** It reuses base components, apply custom styles & translate texts, do some specific stuff and it uses native encapsulation (in order to differentiate from base components) but it doesn't apply business logic. These are integrated in its own branding module that imports shared module.
- **business components:** It reuses branding components and apply own business logic here (when it's used in several views). These are integrated in its own business module that imports branding module. These components implements default angular encapsulation mode.

Then **we have views, that are integrated in its own module & imports business module. It will use branding and or business components, here we're facing some issues regarding to css media queries**. These views uses default angular encapsulation mode.

**The specific case is that in which we're trying to customize for a specific view an input-field in order to behave correctly for responsive cases** (mobile, tablets & desktop on different orientations). In order to do so we're using external plugin angular flex layout (beta 7)

This input-field exist on base component but we're bringing it's branding case. What we want is to change its default width/height set on branding in order to adapt to the div container which will encapsulate it.

This is what we've done so far:

**specific view's scss:**

```
// MEDIA QUERIES
:host ::ng-deep {

  @media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (orientation: portrait)  {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width: 95%;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (orientation: landscape)  {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width:(80px * 2.625);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)  {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width:(80px * 2.9);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (orientation: portrait)  {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width:(80px * 2);
      height:(16px * 1.6);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape)  {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width:(80px * 2.68);
      height:(16px * 1.6);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width:(80px * 3.3);
      height:(16px * 1.6);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width:(80px * 3.5);
      height:(16px * 1.6);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width:(80px * 3.5);
      height:(16px * 1.625);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width:(80px * 1.875);
      height:(16px * 1.625);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width:(80px * 3.75);
      height:(16px * 1.625);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .inputField,
    .inputFieldEditing,
    .inputFieldChanged,
    .inputFieldDisabled {
      width:(80px * 2.5);
      height:(16px * 1.625);
    }
  }
}
```

Previous custom classes exist & are used in branding input-field component in order to change its UX based on different cases.

**branding input-field component template file:**

```
<sh-input-field [id]="id"
                [caption]="caption | translate"
                [(model)]="userInput"
                [placeholder]="placeholder | translate"
                [type]="inputType"
                [color]="color"
                [font-size]="fontsize"
                [isDisabled]="!enabled"
                [style]="{'width': width,
                          'height': height}"
                [status]="status"
                [baseClass]="INPUT_CLASS_ENABLED"
                [extendedClass]="extendedClass"
                [stateClasses]="{
                                  focusedOn: INPUT_CLASS_EDITING,
                                  enabledOn: INPUT_CLASS_ENABLED,
                                  enabledOff: INPUT_CLASS_DISABLED,
                                  valueChanged: INPUT_CLASS_CHANGED
                                }"
              [passwordWeakCaption]="passwordWeakCaption"
              [passwordMediumCaption]="passwordMediumCaption"
              [passwordStrongCaption]="passwordStrongCaption"
              [isPasswordFeedbackShown]="isPasswordFeedbackShown">
</sh-input-field>
```

**branding input-field component scss file:**

```
/* CAPTION */
.uiElemSideCaptionLeft,
.uiElemSideCaptionRight,
.uiElemSideCaptionDisabled {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 2px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  -ms-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #333;
}

.uiElemSideCaptionRight {
  -ms-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.uiElemSideCaptionDisabled {
  -ms-opacity: 0.4;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

/* INPUT-FIELD */
.inputField,
.inputFieldEditing,
.inputFieldChanged,
.inputFieldDisabled {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #979797;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -ms-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.inputFieldEditing {
  -ms-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 14px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #F8E71C;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-style: solid;
}

.inputFieldChanged {
  -ms-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(245, 166, 35, 0.5);
  height: 16px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #979797;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-style: solid;
}

.inputFieldDisabled {
  -ms-opacity: 0.6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #979797;
  border-style: solid;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

**branding input-field component definition:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'br-input-field',
  templateUrl: './input-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-field.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
```

**base input-field component template file:**

```
<div class="sh-input-field-global-container">
  <div class="sh-input-field-label-container" *ngIf="caption !== '' && caption !== undefined && caption !== null">
    <label [for]="id">{{caption}}</label>
  </div>
  <div class="sh-input-field-container" [ngClass]="extendedClass">
    <input *ngIf="controlType !== 'password'"
           [ngClass]="getCssClases('sh-input-field', baseClass)"
           [attr.id]="id"
           [placeholder]="placeholder"
           [disabled]="isDisabled"
           (focus)="InvokeFocus($event)"
           (blur)="InvokeBlur($event)"
           (keyup.enter)="InvokeKeyUpEnterEvent($event)"
           (keyup.escape)="InvokeKeyUpEscapeEvent($event)"
           [(ngModel)]="model"
           [attr.name]="formName"
           [maxLength]="length"
           [type]="controlType"
           [ngStyle]="style"/>
    <input *ngIf="controlType === 'password'"
            [ngClass]="GetCssClases('sh-input-field', baseClass)"
            [attr.id]="id"
            [disabled]="isDisabled"
            (focus)="InvokeFocus($event)"
            (blur)="InvokeBlur($event)"
            (keyup.enter)="InvokeKeyUpEnterEvent($event)"
            (keyup.escape)="InvokeKeyUpEscapeEvent($event)"
            [(ngModel)]="model"
            [attr.name]="formName"
            [maxLength]="length"
            [type]="controlType"
            pPassword
            [promptLabel]="placeholder"
            [weakLabel]="passwordWeakCaption"
            [mediumLabel]="passwordMediumCaption"
            [strongLabel]="passwordStrongCaption"
            [feedback]="isPasswordFeedbackShown"
            [ngStyle]="style"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**base input-field component definition:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sh-input-field',
  templateUrl: './input-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-field.component.scss']
})
```

So what could be wrong here? **Are we using :host :ng-deep incorrectly on specific view?** We've seen if we apply these media queries directly on branding input-field sass file it works fine (removing :host :ng-deep tag)

Comment: It will be easy if you put your code in blitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6 (frok it and post the link)

Comment: I'll do this only if there is no proposed answer that fullfil my concerns, this could be a little difficult to implement more or less quickly as it requires to create four different modules, two components & one view-components :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `:host /deep/` instead of `:host ::ng-deep` as shown below

```
:host /deep/ {
    /*your style goes here*/
}
```

Or

Use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`instead of`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`

Comment: I tried both approaches, and the one which more or less works was setting encapsulation to "ViewEncapsulation.None". **But, I have to add !important to all properties values** set on media queries in order that it makes an effect. Is this a really good practice approach?

Comment: Place media query css below other css and check

Comment: I did that already and it doesn't work, but I don't know the order in which  angular set inline styles on the loaded page, shall it be 1.theme scss, 2. base component scss 3.branding component scss 4. view component scss? **OR** 1.view component scss 2.branding component scss 3. base component scss 4.theme scss?

Comment: Use SCSS mixins for media query instead of normal media query check how to use mixin media query here https://coderwall.com/p/h-dzpa/media-queries-sass-mixin

Comment: This is not a SCSS mixins issue for sure, customs class is not applied on component at all as it doesn't appear on Chrome inspector. I believe it's related to Angular encapsulation, not to a SCSS issue.

Answer (score 1):

> But, I have to add !important to all properties values set on media queries in order that it makes an effect.

To fix this issue I used on scss as [Vikas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3064670/vikas-jadhav) mentioned [in this link](https://coderwall.com/p/h-dzpa/media-queries-sass-mixin).

You can put it in separate file and include it in any file you will use it.

```
$phone : '(max-width: 480px)';
$phone-landscape : '(max-height: 480px)';
$tablet-portrait: '(max-width: 767px)';
$tablet-landscape: '(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) and (max-height: 768px)';
$large-desktop: '(min-width: 1200px)';
$non-retina: 'screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1)';
$retina: '(min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
                    (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), 
                    (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
                    (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
                    (min-resolution: 144dpi), 
                    (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)';

@mixin respond-to($media) {
    @media only screen and #{$media} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

and then use call inside declarations:

```
.bookItem {
    max-height: 450px;
    min-height: 150px;
    padding: 25px;

    @include respond-to($phone) {
      max-height: 150px;
      padding: 15px;
    }
}
```

And it works.